# My datatable doesn't refresh after AJAX Call

Tags: datatables

Hello I have set up my data table. I am able to show data on page load. However when I click on next page, the call is made to server side and it returns data, however the data table doesn't refresh. Can anyone tell me what is going on ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   //get Data Tables Query
   buildDataTables();
});


function buildDataTables() {
    if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#locationTable')) {
        $('#locationTable').DataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '/Home/GetDataTablesQuery',
            paging: true,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "Address1", "name": "Address 1" },
                { "mData": "City", "name": "City" },
                { "mData": "Size", "name": "Approx SF" },
                { "mData": "StoreNumber", "name": "Store #" },
            ]
        });
    }
```

How do I refresh datatable data on pagination ??

Comment: Can you show that code where on clicking you are making call to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what the problem is. I was always setting sEcho to 10 in the response. we need to pass the value sent by DataTable to the server.

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        public AdvancedJsonResult GetDataTablesQuery(LocationsFilter locationFilter)
        {
            List<LocationInfo> locationInfos = new List<LocationInfo>();
            int totalRecords = 0;

            locationFilter.CurrentPage = (locationFilter.iDisplayStart/locationFilter.iDisplayLength) + 1;

            ////Default Page Number to 1 if Zero
            //if (locationFilter.CurrentPage == 0)
            //{
            //    locationFilter.CurrentPage = 1;
            //}

            //Default Page Size
            locationFilter.PageSize = locationFilter.iDisplayLength;

            //Get Records
            locationInfos = _LocationInfoLogic.Get(locationFilter, out totalRecords);
            var dataTablesResponse = new { aaData = locationInfos.ToArray(), iTotalRecords = totalRecords, iTotalDisplayRecords = totalRecords, sEcho = locationFilter.sEcho };
            return new AdvancedJsonResult { Data = dataTablesResponse };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is write the below code on success call of ajax
`$("#datatble").DataTable().ajax.reload();`

and if you want to keep the response on the same page
`$("#tag").DataTable().ajax.reload(null,false);`